# Wordpress new site in Multisite - MySQL schema for creation - add trigger

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers, database-schema, multisite

I have Wordpress Multisite with few sites. Now I need create for every newly created site a MySQL trigger based od postmeta table. I modified a schema.php with this trigger, but if I create new site, it seems schema.php (wp-admin/includes/) is not using for creating new tables for this new site. 
Wordpress have stored SQL creation script in some else php file, or what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want to create new table when a new site is created?

Comment: Default tables for site is properly created, prefix "wp_" + blog_id + "table name". But If I add query for new (not default) table or mine trigger to schema.php. Nothing happened after I add new site.

Comment: confused.. actually what do you want to happen when a new site is created?

Comment: Only add new trigger based on "wp_" + blog_id + "postmeta" table